# RailsAdmin handle callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

How do I can check if model was updated via rails_admin. Is there anything like rails_admin_before_save?

If it wasn`t implemented yet. Is there any ways to get such behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no `rails_admin_before_save` callback... no callbacks for specific rails admin actions...
but RailsAdmin runs the models callbacks,

so if you have a `before_save` callback in your model, it'll run...

as for checking you can check that the model fields was updated appropriately...
you can add auditing and history extensions (plugins) for rails admin to record every change that happens to the models like these

- https://github.com/franc/rails_admin_histeroid
- https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Papertrail
- https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Internal-audit-plugin

Comment: Thanks for reply... but I asked about specific callbacks. In model callback you cannot determine source of changes admin or background job.. etc. I`ve found solution override ra dsl for handle controller logic.

Comment: ok please add what you found as a solution so that you could help the others